# Jquery datepicker not fetching results via URL from MySql datebase?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I'm struggling to find out why this doesn't work, I trying to fetching from jquery datepicker requests via URL any dates from the DATETIME column in my datebase called time? Below I'v added a picture of the URL being sent to server and of time column.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  <label for="from">From</label>
  <input type="text" name="from" id="from"/>
  <label for="to">To:</label>
  <input type="text" name="to" id="to"/>

   $( "#from" ).datepicker();
   $( "#to" ).datepicker();

$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", {dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyT00:00:00', showAnim: 'show' });
$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", {dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyT23:59:59',showAnim: 'show'});

$('#to').val(to);
$('#from').val(from);
```

PHP:

```
var from = getParameterByName('from'); 
var to = getParameterByName('to');

var from = parseDateTime($('#from').val()); 
var to = parseDateTime($('#to').val()); 

my.php?=from='+from+'&to='+to+'&rand='+Math.random()

$query = 'SELECT * FROM register WHERE time BETWEEN ( "#from" ) AND  ( "#to" )';
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['time']."<br>";
}
```

[image: URL]

[image: column]

Comment: Try this: `$( "#from" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date(from));`

Comment: Thanks, but by doing it that way I only get the date and not time aswell.

Comment: You can not have time in `datepicker`. You must be looking for _DateTimePicker_

Comment: Even if I change it just to date only I still get no results ?

Comment: Provided code is incomplete..Php code is not necessary. Try providing a fiddle which contains input fields and your efforts to set the date..

Comment: Iv added the inputs to the code above. Efforts to set date, do you mean a picture of me adding dates to the input boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) method which Sets the date for the datepicker

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date('10/12/2012'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2wpp2qc1/)

You can use `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon` to add the time.

Try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2wpp2qc1/1/) and this with formatted date and time: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2wpp2qc1/2/

Comment: As mentioned in the comments earlier, you can not have time in `datepicker` Use `datetimepicker` instead.

Comment: Thanks for code above, but that does fetch from time column via URL? and I need to fetch time aswell in order to show results ?

Comment: Dude, Read the documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ You can no have __time__ in datepicker. Use http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ for that

Comment: Im using this  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />  think maybe this wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99231/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-jonas).

Comment: Sorry, this didnt work jquery-ui-timepicker-addon, if you look at the link I send you earlier your understand what I trying to achieve.

Comment: But on the web link I had sent you they dont seem to use a addon at all?

Comment: They are not expecting date at all. Just printing it using formatter. User will never be able to edit the time..

Comment: ok, so your printing out to look at code better?
But you can edit the date and write time in to show when the marker is shown on the map, is a tricky one this one i know?

Comment: You want to go private chat?